# Can hangout-chat reconize it`s pc web or mobile? I want it to make itself auto-resizing

Tags: google-hangouts

Can hangout-chat reconize it`s pc web or mobile? I want it to make itself auto-resizing.

I want the each chat conversation box to be resized automatically depends on the size.

Thank you all!